# WooCommerce how to get post custom field data and add it to the order details page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, woocommerce-theming

I'm so close on my first WooCommerce custom field.

My problem appears to be getting the custom field's entered data posting onto the Order Details page.

For the life of me I can't seem to locate the issue with this code:

```
                // Register main datepicker jQuery plugin script
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_picker' );
            function enabling_date_picker() {

                // Only on front-end and checkout page
                if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

                // Load the datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
                wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
            }

            // Call datepicker functionality in your custom text field
            add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1);
            function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

                date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
                $mydateoptions = array('' => __('Select PickupDate', 'woocommerce' ));

                echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
                <h3>'.__('Empty Cylinder Collection').'</h3>';

                // YOUR SCRIPT HERE BELOW 
                echo '
                <script>
                    jQuery(function($){
                        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
                    });
                </script>';

               woocommerce_form_field( 'cylinder_collect_date', array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                    'id'            => 'datepicker',
                    'required'      => false,
                    'label'         => __('Collection Date'),
                    'placeholder'       => __('Select Date'),
                    'options'     =>   $mydateoptions
                    ),$checkout->get_value( 'cylinder_collect_date' ));

                echo '</div>';
            }
            /**
             * Process the checkout
             **/
            add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

            function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
                global $woocommerce;

                // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
                if (!$_POST['cylinder_collect_date'])
                     wc_add_notice( '<strong>Collection Date</strong> ' . __( 'is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            }

             /**
             * Update the order meta with custom fields values
             * */
             add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

             function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id) {

            if (!empty($_POST['cylinder_collect_date'])) {
                update_post_meta($order_id, 'Pick-up Empty Cylinder', sanitize_text_field($_POST['cylinder_collect_date']));
            }
            }

            /**
             * Display Custom Shipping fields and custom fields in custom area in the Order details area in Woocommerce->orders
             *  */
            add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_fields_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);

            function my_custom_fields_display_admin_order_meta($order) {
            echo "<h4>Empty Cylinder Collection</h4>";
            echo '<p><strong>' . __('Collection Date') . ':</strong><br> ' . get_post_meta($order->id, 'cylinder_collect_date', true) . '</p>';

             }

             /**
             * Display Custom Billing fields in the Order details area in Woocommerce->orders
              * */
             add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_billing_fields_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);

            function my_custom_billing_fields_display_admin_order_meta($order) {
            echo "<h4>Empty Cylinder Collection</h4>";
            echo '<p><strong>' . __('Collection Date') . ':</strong><br> ' . get_post_meta($order->id, 'cylinder_collect_date', true) . '</p>';
             }
```

I am using Flatsome theme and I am adding this code to the theme's inc file

refer: https://stage.helium2go.com.au

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with the following code

```
/**
 * Display Custom Shipping fields and custom fields in custom area in the Order details area in Woocommerce->orders
 *  */
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_fields_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);

function my_custom_fields_display_admin_order_meta($order) {
echo "<h4>Empty Cylinder Collection</h4>";
echo '<p><strong>' . __('Collection Date') . ':</strong><br> ' . get_post_meta($order->id, 'Pick-up Empty Cylinder', true) . '</p>';

 }

 /**
 * Display Custom Billing fields in the Order details area in Woocommerce->orders
  * */
 add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_billing_fields_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);

function my_custom_billing_fields_display_admin_order_meta($order) {
echo "<h4>Empty Cylinder Collection</h4>";
echo '<p><strong>' . __('Collection Date') . ':</strong><br> ' . get_post_meta($order->id, 'Pick-up Empty Cylinder', true) . '</p>';
 }
```

I needed to use: Pick-up Empty Cylinder